# Qt under Ubuntu - typing accents

Tags: linux, qt, input, localization, keyboard

Users of my application report, that they cannot use Dead Keys for typing accent characters in Brazilian Portuguese. The application is open source (SQLiteStudio) and I distribute it (precompiled packages) together with Qt libraries (dynamically linked).

This was tested with Qt 5.12.2 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I managed to reproduce it by doing following:

- I have a usual US-layout keyboard
- Install Ubuntu on VirtualBox
- Choose "Portuguese (Brazil)" keyboard from settings
- To confirm it works in general - I hit `;` in any application and I get "ç", as expected. This one works also in my app.
- Try typing characters using "dead keys" in pre-installed Ubuntu apps (Terminal, Writer, etc), like:

  - ḉ (by holding `AltGr` and hitting `;`, followed by hitting `;` once more, but without `AltGr`)
  - ã (by typing `'` and then `a`)
- Try typing the same characters using "dead keys" in my Qt application.

These combinations simply do not work. Instead of "ḉ" I get just "ç" and instead of "ã" I get just "a".

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing to do?

Comment: I have the same problem. I was able to compile SQLiteStudio from the source, and the program compiled by me recognizes dead keys; but it is very fragile, it crashes all the time. The precompiled package, instead, works perfectly well, but no dead keys. Did you manage to resolve the problem?

Comment: This issue seems to be related https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/issues/3069